# .exe file cannot be deleted because it is open in Host Process for Windows Services; how do I delete it?

Tags: windows-7, usb-flash-drive

How do I delete this file? When I try, I get this error message:

[image: this is what it looks like]

I've tried using cmd prompt for shortcut files i.e. `attrib -h -r -s /s /d g:\*.*`

I've tried unlocker to delete the .exe files as per the other users on internet.

USB security drive isn't able to delete the file either and I've even formatted it but none of them are working. It has just been a week or two since I bought this pen drive so a help with proper guidance would mean a lot to me.

Comment: What's the make and model of the USB drive that has this file? Was it a file that was put on the drive after you first used it or did it come pre-installed?

Comment: the pen-drive is **hp v250W** and it wasn't a file i put on the drive and i don't think it was pre-installed either

Comment: Open task manager and tick show all processes, then go to services tab and find the exe, right click on it and select stop process, then try deleting the file

Answer (score 0):

#### How do I delete this file?

You can use [MoveFile](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897556) to schedule a delete command for the next reboot:

```
movefile ObIzqBT.exe ""
```

---

#### MoveFile usage

> The included `MoveFile` utility allows you to schedule move and delete
>   commands for the next reboot:
>
> ```
> usage: movefile [source] [dest]
> ```
>
> Specifying an empty destination ("") deletes the source at boot.
>
> An example that deletes `test.exe` is:
>
> ```
> movefile test.exe ""
> ```

Source [MoveFile](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897556)

---

#### Disclaimer

I am not affiliated with Windows Sysinternals in any way, I am just an end user of the software.